# How to get names or id of all modules to be installed/upgraded

Tags: module, installation, odoo, upgrade, openerp-7

I need list of all modules to be installed/upgraded when i am installing/upgrading particular module. How can i get this?

For e.g if i am installing project_issue it will install crm, project etc.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by 2 ways

1 - From web interface :

> Settings >> apps

then open the particular module

from technical data tab you will find all the dependencies modules of the module

2 - From module files :
open the desciptor file of the module "**openerp**.py" which you can find in the module directory in your addons path, you can find the dependencies in the file